# Oracle SQL Query Logic

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table structure/data like below,

```
Emp_Id  flag
```

---

```
101     Y
102     N
103     Y
103     N
```

Employee flag might be below 3 combinations,

1. only he has "Y" (eg., 101)
2. only he has "N" (eg., 102)
3. he have both "Y" and "N" (eg., 103)

I need results like below,

```
Emp_Id   Status
----------------
101      Auto
102      Manual
103      Partial
```

Comment: `select emp_id, decode(listagg(distinct flag), 'Y', 'Auto', 'N', 'Manual', 'Partial')) as status from table_name group by emp_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `case` clause can be used as follows:

The idea is to see if the total number of flags `count(1)` equals the number of `YES` or `NO` flags.

```
select Emp_Id,
       case 
       when sum(CASE WHEN flag='Y' THEN 1 END) = count(1) then 'Auto' 
       when sum(CASE WHEN flag='N' THEN 1 END) = count(1) then 'Manual'
       else 'Partial' 
       end as Status
from   mytable
group by Emp_Id
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Vl5F9U0L)

Comment: Oracle doesn't have boolean SQL datatype, so `sum(flag='Y')` is syntactically incorrect

Comment: [Oracle fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BtHQ7_bK) which shows the answer's code not working in Oracle and one method of how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the remark @astentx and MTO .. I will take your fix

Answer (score 0):

You can use case over average value of flag converted to 0/1 value:

```sql
Select Emp_Id,
  case avg(case when flag = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end)
  when 0 then 'manual'
  when 1 then 'auto'
  else 'partial' end Status
from mytable
group by Emp_Id
```

Demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/YTFyF-Oi).